# How do I block /plugins/ folder from public access?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I protect "plugin" folder via .htaccess?

http://www.example.com/plugins/ my files are here

I want to prevent visitors from accessing to `/plugins/` folder, but when I tried blocking it using code below, my files inside this folder stopped working. Please pardon my grammatical errors.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*(plugins).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "accessing". Presumably a browser to access files in here otherwise the site breaks, as you say.

At a guess, you're referring to going to that directory and it listing all the files within it. If that is the case, the following would work:

```
<location /plugins>
  Options -Indexes
</location>
```